# What programming languages can be used to develop in Google Fuchsia?

Tags: fuchsia

What programming languages can be used to develop **Google Fuchsia** applications?

Answer (score 8):

> Google Fuchsia required Development SDK : Flutter.

**Google Fuchsia Supported languages**

- C/C++
- Dart
- FIDL
- Go
- Rust
- Flutter modules (to write a graphical module)

**official documentation**
https://fuchsia.googlesource.com/docs/+/ea2fce2874556205204d3ef70c60e25074dc7ffd/development/README.md

Answer (score 4):

The apps are primarily developed in Flutter SDK, in Dart.

But reportedly, apps made for Android are going to work seamlessly on Fuchsia as well:
https://www.businessinsider.com/google-fuchsia-run-android-apps-2018-4?IR=T

Answer (score 1):

Depends on which layer you are working, if it is about low level, around kernel then you should consider C, C++. FIDL and all are interface definitions but the programming language is C, C++. You should have all the focuses on **C++** to start with.

If you are into application development then you should get your hands dirty with **Rust** programming which will be eventually be developed in Flutter. And the internal runtime mechanism is Dart. So concentrate in Rust to start with.

Answer (score 1):

Google has added Python to its [Fuchsia Programming Language Policy](https://fuchsia.dev/fuchsia-src/contribute/governance/policy/programming_languages).

Please note that if you intend to write code outside the [Fuchsia Platform Source Tree](https://fuchsia.googlesource.com/), not all languages ​​are supported

The current complete list:

- [C](https://fuchsia.dev/fuchsia-src/development/languages/c-cpp)
- [C++](https://fuchsia.dev/fuchsia-src/development/languages/c-cpp)
- [Dart](https://fuchsia.dev/fuchsia-src/development/languages/dart)
- [Rust](https://fuchsia.dev/fuchsia-src/development/languages/rust) (*not supported for end-devs*)
- [Go](https://fuchsia.dev/fuchsia-src/development/languages/go) (***not approved***)
- [Python](https://fuchsia.dev/fuchsia-src/development/languages/python) (*not supported for end-devs*)